# building boost with unicode regex enabled on x64 windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, 64-bit

Am trying to build boost on x64 windows. So far all is going well, however, I can't persuade boost to find the ICU library.

I have a binary release of x64 ICU available at `c:\dev` so, using the MSVC x64 tools prompt I am issuing the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\dev\bin;
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\dev\include;
set LIB=%LIB%;c:\dev\lib;
bootstrap.bat
bjam -sHAVE_ICU=1 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --address-model=64 \
     --build-type=complete release
```

which works fine, apart from the fact `bjam` keeps responding with:

```
- has_icu builds = no
```

Any ideas? I'm using MSVC10 x64 Prompt if that helps. The ICU library is the 64-bit version for Windows available [here](http://apps.icu-project.org/icu-jsp/downloadPage.jsp?ver=4.6&base=c) and meets boost's requirement of being built with the same toolchain (MSVC10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [this patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/66699) from Boost SVN and make sure `ICU_PATH` is defined, for more information see [Boost bug#4864](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4864) .